# Does Rails Devise not automatically send an email on user signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Did they remove that. I'm noticing with the latest rails devise gem, that signing up for a new account does not create an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only send you an email if you have enabled the `:confirmable` module, which is off by default.